# Listener in primefaces, which component to use?

Tags: events, user-interface, event-handling, primefaces

What component used to send alerts to the interface without using the poll or having to call some method every second. I mean, I want to act as a trigger, a hange in the database made ​​by a user to be sent to another user interface, which is received in the event view. Is this possible?

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is "Push mechanism" Primefaces calls it  [PrimePush](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf)...